# Negation with "Not" and except NULL values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, filter, feature-filter

Is this intentional or an error?

In QGIS I am trying to filter a layer by the attribute `"Foot"`.
I can easily filter by writing `"Foot"='no'` and it behaves like expected.

But when I want to see *"the opposite"* and write

```
"foot" != 'no'
```

all features with `NULL` values for `"Foot"` are filtered away too.

So if I want *"the opposite"* I need to write:

```
"foot" != 'no' or "foot" is null
```

I do not think this is logical, is not it?

Comment: This is ternary logic; it may be counterintuitive, but it is, by definition, "logical".

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: see [comment by @bixb0012](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448695/negation-with-not-and-except-null-values-in-qgis#comment732811_448707): the solution depends on the data source behind the layer, as SQL support is depends on it. This solution works for Geopackage layers.*

---

Correct syntax to filter including `NULL` values is using `is` and `not` instead of `=` or `!=` :

`"foot" is not 'no'`

The logic behind this behaviour is that when selecting features based on content of a field, `NULL` values are generally ignored, they are treated as "undefined". So `NULL` is neither `= 'no'` nor `!= 'no'`.

To handle comparisons with NULL values, you need to use the operators `is` or `is not`, see: https://ramkedem.com/en/sql-server-is-null/

See also here for details: [Difference between `=` and `is` in sql server: Nothing equals `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25641783/13651925)

Comment: Many flavors of SQL do not support this use of the `IS` predicate and will return a syntax error.

Comment: Might be so, but the question here was about privider feature filter and the answer was specifically for this context to solve OP's problem.

Comment: I commented because the OP never stated what data source is behind the layer, and SQL support is dependent on the data source.  Although `"foot" is not 'no'` will work for a GPKG layer, it will fail on a file geodatabase, SQL Server, Oracle, and many other data sources.

Comment: @bixb0012 thanks a lot for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`"foot" is distinct from 'no'`

It should keep the NULLs

Comment: `"foot" is distinct from 'no'` returns an error. Correct syntax is `"foot" is not 'no'`

Comment: The OP's original syntax, `"foot" != 'no' or "foot" is null`, is the most portable syntax.  Not all flavors of SQL support `datatype/expression IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM datatype/expression`, and even those that support it don't implement it exactly the same.

Comment: @Babel it does not for me. Maybe it depends on the kind of data source

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification that "is" and "is not" behave differently - at least it worked on the temporary scratch layer I had in my project.